# Sharing home folder between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04 running inside VMWare

Tags: windows-7, vmware, ntfs, sharing, user-profile

I'm looking for a way to share my user profile between Windows 7 and Ubuntu as guest OS inside VMWare.

Are there any caveats for such an odd marriage, particularly in using NTFS with Ubuntu, on directories that will be written by by both OSes (Firefox profile, etc.)?

[EDIT] I know about VMWare's "shared folders" feature, what I'm asking if there are any caveats associated with doing something like this, ie. having Ubuntu use NTFS as the home dir, and having it potentially modify things Windows might not be happy about.

Comment: Expect performance slower if you use a Shared Folder as your home dir. The file and folder permissions are the only one will not work in my opinion. If I were you, I wouldn't map the Shared Folder directly to my home folder, but symlink the wanted folders one by one from the shares.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Shared Folders" feature of WMware. You can read more here: [Using Shared Folders](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html).

Answer (score 0):

An option could be syncing your folders with UbuntuOne, Dropbox or some other app.

Comment: In my situation I need to have changes reflected live, and not be dependent on an Internet connection.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @tijybba While not suitable to this OP's particular needs, this does answer the question as asked, and it may help others searching with similar problems. I see no good reason for this to be deleted or converted to a comment.